# Proving technique for proving $BB^T$ is positive semidefinite for rectangular $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose $B$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Prove that $BB^T$ is positive semidefinite.

Can someone give a fairly good proof?

Inputs are greatly appreciated. The question is listed above.

Comment: What does it mean for $BB^T$ to be positive semidefinite? What can you say about the product $x^T B B^T x$ for arbitrary vectors $x$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For column vectors $a,b$, their inner (or scalar or dot) product is
$$\langle a,b\rangle = a^Tb$$
using matrix product, and $a^Ta=\langle a,a\rangle=\|a\|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$BB^T$ is positive semidefinite if for any vector $x$
$$
xBB^Tx^T\ge0
$$
Let $u=xB$. Then,
$$
xBB^Tx^T=uu^T=|u|^2\ge0
$$