# Is $AA^T$ positive semidefinite?

Tags: matrices

I have a very short question.

Is $AA^T$ positive semidefinite, i.e. $x^T AA^Tx\geqslant 0$ for suitable $x$?

Comment: Closely related questions, e.g., [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133350/help-me-understand-a-line-in-an-ata-is-positive-semi-definite-proof), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387096/proving-technique-for-proving-bbt-is-positive-semidefinite-for-rectangular-b), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730421/is-aat-a-positive-definite-symmetric-matrix), also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68897/symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-question) (with the middle matrix equal to the identity).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let $y=A^Tx$.
$x^T AA^Tx=y^Ty=\sum_{k=1}^N y_k^2\geqslant 0$

So your answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

$AA^{T}$ is positively semidefinite $\Leftrightarrow$ it is obviously true that $A^{T}A$ is positively semidefinite. We'll prove the right.

It is true that $A^{T}A$ is symmetric. Let $x$ be a non-zero column vector. Then we have:
$x^{T}A^{T}Ax = (Ax)^{T}(Ax)$.

Notice that $Ax$ is also a non-zero column vector so $(Ax)^{T}(Ax)$ is the square of the inner product of $Ax$

Then:  $(Ax)^{T}(Ax) = ||Ax||^{2} \geq  0$. Done ! Sorry for my English